# Amazon aws cli query starts_with

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

Trying to filter out only repos that start with name but always got empty collection back. I can see the values there when running without the `starts_with` option

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --query "repositories[?starts_with(repositoryName, 'test') == 'true'].repositoryName"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use Backticks for pattern matching.

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[?starts_with(repositoryName, `stage`) == `true`]'
```

or If  you want just ARN or NAME then you can use

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --query 'repositories[?starts_with(repositoryName, `stage`) == `true`]|[].[repositoryName,repositoryUri]'
```